# Autofilter, Copy columns, Paste Special (Values only) in first open cell in another spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I am working on a massive project and have run into an unanticipated difficulty.  I didn't think I would need such a complicated code, but I do. I have cut and pasted the pieces of code that I think I need, but I keep getting errors when trying to run it. Here is what I have so far and I know quite a bit is missing.  I am going to post the code that I have so far and see if someone can help me find the missing parts. I hope that my intentions for the code are clear:

Autofilter, copy columns from the filtered data, then paste in "General Level" sheet in first open cell in column B and then I have an auto-fill down formula for column A based on Column B.

```
Sub PullNewstsfromMPtoGL()

Sheets("Master Placement").Range("$A$1:$AX999999").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="N"

Sheets("Master Placement").Range("A:I,AA:AC,AN:AQ").Copy

Sheets("General Level").Select
Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
```

Comment: I have reduced the formula a bit and decided to autofilter the data myself and was able to use the following code successfully for a time; however, it is now giving me an error message.

Here is the code: 
`Sheets("MASTER PLACEMENT").Range("A:I,AA:AC,AN:AQ").Copy
Sheets("General Level").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`

Here is the error message: "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be more than one issue at play here. The reason you are getting an error is that you can't paste anything into cells that are beyond the boundaries of the destination sheet even if the copied cells are blank. However, the error I get running your initally posted code is:
[image: 1004 Copy and paste areas are not the same size and shape]

When you copy a filtered column, the number of rows copied will be the number of rows in your filtered list **plus the number of blank rows.** The solution is to reduce the copied range to the minimum number of rows to capture all of your data (which will also speed up your code).

So define a LastRow variable to use in the copy operation. Revised code as follows:

```
Sub PullNewstsfromMPtoGL()
Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("Master Placement").Range("$A$1:$AX999999").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="N"
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Assuming row 1 has headings otherwise change 2s to 1s
Sheets("Master Placement").Range("A2:I" & LastRow _
    & ",AA2:AC" & LastRow _
    & ",AN2:AQ" & LastRow).Copy
With Sheets("General Level")
'No need to select paste range
    .Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    LastRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
End With
'Optional - clear filter from Master Placement
Sheets("Master Placement").Range("$A$1:$AX999999").AutoFilter Field:=6
End Sub
```

I couldn't reproduce the `PasteSpecial method of Range class failed` error but I usually associate that with there being nothing to paste. Selecting cells won't clear the clipboard but editing something or clearing a filter will. You said in your OP that

> I have cut and pasted the pieces of code that I think I need

so I wonder if there was a line of code not copied that could have cleared the clipboard?

Comment: YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER!  This does exactly what I need it do and without error. Thank you so much Mark!